# Поставить сервис на паузу

Tags: android

Как поставить сервис на паузу, чтобы он не реагировал на события, которые его касаются, а через определённое время (через Handler в этом же сервисе) сервис снова возобновить?

Такой код делает один цикл и вызывает ошибку

**Сервис:**

```
// Какие-то действия
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Если это Ваш сервис - то просто создайте в нем буленовую переменную, которая будет регулировать процесс "обрабатывать сообщение или нет". Также нужно создать специальное событие (или два) для включения/выключения сервиса. Они будут просто переключать этот флажок.

Понятно, что на событие "сервис включись" сервис объязан реагировать, хотя флажок в этот момент скорее всего будет в состоянии "не реагировать".

С помощью Handler сервис может сам себе послать сообщение о включении.

Comment: Вот я и подумал, возобновит ли сам себя сервис Хандлером, если он будет отключен? Если так, то набросок такой:
 
    //действия
    //стоп сервиса
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
           {
               @Override
               public void run()
               {
                  // старт сервиса через 10 секунд
               }
           }, 10000);